# Sending some Data thru httplistener

Tags: c#-4.0, httplistener

I have to write a Windowsservice witch makes the bookings (solved), the ID for the booking I'm getting from and RFID Card. Reading out the ID is solved to. The only Problem now is that i have to transfer the ID from the RFID reader to the WinService. I should use an HTTP Listener. 
The codes on MSDN are not very instructive for me.

```
if (!HttpListener.IsSupported)
        {
            WriteLog("Windows XP SP2, Server 2003 oder höher wird benötigt um HttpListener verwenden zu können.");
            return;
        }
        if (uri == null || uri.Length == 0)
        {
            WriteLog("Die zu verwendende URI ist leer.");
        }

        HttpListener listener = new HttpListener();
        foreach(string s in uri)
        {
            listener.Prefixes.Add(s);
        }
        listener.Start();

        // Durch GetContext wird die Methode solange gestoppt bis eine request reinkommt.
        HttpListenerContext context = listener.GetContext();
        HttpListenerRequest request = context.Request;
```

So how do i catch the value?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [this](http://webserver.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=HttpListener&referringTitle=Examples) Library from CodePlex. There you can register an OnRequest-Handler and there you can do somthing on a request.